# System standard sound in Python

Tags: python, audio, wxpython, system-sounds

How play standard system sounds from a Python script?

I'm writing a GUI program in wxPython that needs to beep on events to attract user's attention, maybe there are functions in wxPython I can utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_dialogfunctions.html#wxbell), you could use wx.Bell() function (not tested though)

Answer (score 3):

on windows you could use [`winsound`](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html#module-winsound) and I suppose [`curses.beep`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.beep) on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> **wxTopLevelWindow::RequestUserAttention**
>
> **void RequestUserAttention(int flags =
>   wxUSER_ATTENTION_INFO)**
>
> Use a system-dependent way to attract
>   users attention to the window when it
>   is in background.
>
> flags may have the value of either
>   wxUSER_ATTENTION_INFO (default) or
>   wxUSER_ATTENTION_ERROR which results
>   in a more drastic action. When in
>   doubt, use the default value.
>
> Note that this function should
>   normally be only used when the
>   application is not already in
>   foreground.
>
> This function is currently implemented
>   for Win32 where it flashes the window
>   icon in the taskbar, and for wxGTK
>   with task bars supporting it.